# Regarding a product of two matrices where one of them is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assuming I have two matrices, one is some matrix $A$, the other is an invertible matrix $(A-I)$.
Knowing that $A^2 = A$, I have to prove that $A=0$.

This was a question on my test, and through a few steps of using what is known I managed to reach this:
$(A-I)A = 0$

So I wrote in my final sentence as a mean to end the proof, that knowing $(A-I)$ is invertible, hence $(A-I)\neq0$ we can say that $A=0$ .

Obviously, a product of two matrices being $0$ does not mean that one of the matrices is $0$, but doesn't the fact that we know $(A-I)$ is invertible change this, hence $A=0$?

My proof was completely disregarded and I got none of the points, and my professor said that is "a serious mistake" but I can't come up with a counter-example to disprove what I wrote. I'd appreciate if someone could enlighten me about this. Thanks.

Comment: Since $(A-I)$ is invertible you can multiply both sides of the equation by $(A-I)^{-1}$.

Comment: Note that $(I-A)$ is non-singular. Since $A$ is idempotent, $(I-A)$ is also idempotent. But if $(I-A)$ is idempotent and non-singular, then $(I-A)=I$, so $A=0$

Comment: "I can't come up with a counter-example" -- this is because that is what the theorem is saying (if $A - I$ is invertible and $(A - I)A = 0$, then $A = 0$). But you can't assume what you want to prove.

Comment: Being more specific, are there two matrices where one is invertible, the other is non-zero and the product is zero? That's what I meant as a counter example, because that's what lead me to write what I wrote.

Comment: No, there are no counterexamples to that. If $B$ is invertible and $BC = 0$, then left-multiplying by $B^{-1}$ on both sides gives $C = B^{-1}0 = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic has a major flaw. $AB=0$ and $A\neq 0$ do not imply $B=0$.

But $A-I$ invertible, gives $(A-I)^{-1}$ exists. So $$(A-I)A=0\\
\Rightarrow (A-I)^{-1}(A-I)A=(A-I)^{-1}\cdot0\\ \Rightarrow I\cdot A=0\\ \Rightarrow A=0.$$ Proved.